# How to set condition in PostgreSQL JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have such postgres statement, which shows all JSONs where `transferToken = fake_token`:

```
select voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson from voucherbatchtransaction
    where voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson::jsonb @> '{"transferToken": "fake_token"}'
```

But I need to add logical negation. Of course, I could just add `where not`, but that's not what I need, because this statement will be used in other statements. I mean, I need to add logical negation IN JSON itself.

In **pseudocode** it would look like this:

```
where voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson::jsonb @> '{"transferToken": !"fake_token"}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be look like this:

```
WHERE (voucherbatchtransaction.detailsjson ->> 'transferToken')
      IS DISTINCT FROM 'fake_token'
```